# Is there a way to get HttpOnly cookies data in a java applet?

Tags: java, cookies, applet, httponly

My applet uses `HttpOnly` cookies by default. The below mentioned piece of code works in **IE11**, and gets the cookie data inside the applet. But it does not work in **Firefox 52 ESR**, and it returns a `null` value.

```
cookies = CookieHandler.getDefault().get(new URI(URLHelper.getContextPath(this) + "/images/gui"),new HashMap<String, List<String>>());
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

[Excerpt from Oracle FAQ](https://java.com/en/download/faq/firefox_java.xml)

> Firefox no longer provides NPAPI support (technology required for Java applets)
>   As of September, 2018, Firefox no longer offers a version which supports NPAPI, the technology required to run Java applets. The Java Plugin for web browsers relies on the cross-platform plugin architecture NPAPI, which had been supported by all major web browsers for over a decade. The 64 bit version of Firefox has never supported NPAPI, and Firefox version 52ESR is the last release to support the technology. It is below the security baseline, and no longer supported.

[Excerpt from Oracle enable Java in my web browser](https://java.com/en/download/help/enable_browser.xml)

> Firefox has removed NPAPI plugin support, and therefore Java Plugin cannot be enabled in Firefox browser version 52 and above.